# TBB Parallel_for and lambda

Tags: c++, multithreading, lambda, parallel.for

is it possible to do something like this with a parallel_for

```
int a = 4, b = 5;
int c = 0;
int d = 0;

for(int I=0;I<100;I++)
{
    for(int J=0;J<100;J++)
    {
        c = a+b;
        cout << c << endl;
    }

    for(int K=0;k<100;k++)
    {
        d = c*2;
        cout << d << endl;
    }
}
```

If a parallel_for is applied in this type of layout where a certain action must happen before another it can cause issues because the threads can run at different times

Is there a way to gaurentee the first for loop will run before the second?

Comment: This would be with a lambda using a blocked_2D range which would replace the for loop variables ?